# Is that actually the White Witch in the Ritual Scene?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia

Spoilers if you haven't seen or read *Prince Caspian*.

---

So, in *Prince Caspian*, some evil guys:

> Attempt to resurrect the White Witch.

In the movie, I'm aware this doesn't exactly happen in the books.

> The White Witch appears to Edmund and then Peter and tries to convince them to sacrifice some blood to complete the ritual.

But my question is, is this actually Jadis in some sort of Spirit form or is it more like Voldemort's Locket? I know that's not a perfect analogy because the locket actually had a part of Voldemort's soul inside it.

> To expand upon this, was this simply a magical illusion appearing as the White Witch or was that some remnant part of Jadis' spirit or soul who was actually talking to the Pevensie boys from beyond the grave?

I understand that's not the clearest question ever but I think I've gotten my point across. I'm also aware that in the books:

> The White Witch doesn't herself actually appear in this scene.

So the evidence would be limited but give me everything you've got.

Comment: what does IMDB say? If it's the same actress then odds are good

Comment: @NKCampbell It is the same actress and IMDB lists it as 'The White Witch' but I don't accept this as evidence. I love IMDB but it is sometimes wrong *Cough Cough* Rick and Morty release dates.

Comment: okay....what do the credits say? :)

Comment: according to wikipedia, which lists the source as being the film's audio commentary (would be a terribly odd lie), Tilda Swinton indeed reprises her role: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia:_Prince_Caspian#cite_note-commentary-20

Answer (score 7):

The movie takes some license with the White Witch scene. She doesn't actually appear in the book, but in the movie, to drum the tension in the scene up, they have her appear in some spirit form. Here's the scene in question

We know it's her because this is what [she says in the movie](http://www.narniaweb.com/features/Prince-Caspian-Movie-Script.pdf)

> *Peter pushes Caspian away and points his sword at the Witch.*
>
> **Peter:** Get away from him!
>
> *The White Witch falls back a little.*
>
> **White Witch:** Peter dear... I have missed you. Come, just one
> drop.

She's addressing Peter by name. Considering some 200 years have passed in Narnia, it's highly unlikely anyone else would recognize Peter solely by sight. Given that she wants a "drop of Adam's blood", it's not just some phantasm. The implication is she will be reincarnated if she gets it.

Comment: I get what you're saying but I still think it could be a part of the spell. Still though this is a good answer and I'll consider it.